# Converting Base64 string to GIF image

Tags: c#, image, mono, base64, animated-gif

For a side project I am trying to make a simple executable that takes 2 arguments:

1. Text file path (contains a Base64 encoded animated GIF) (example base.txt)
2. Name of the GIF to export (example hello.gif)

The way I am thinking it should all go is this:

1. It opens and reads the data from the file
2. It takes the data and decodes the Base64 string
3. It then saves the data as an animated GIF

Now of course there are some intermediate steps that need to happen but I don't think I need to cover that at the moment.

So in the end I am left with the following C# file which should do what I want.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Base642Img
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 2) {
                byte[] buffer;
                String imageData;
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream (args [0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                try {
                    int length = (int)fileStream.Length;
                    buffer = new byte[length];
                    int count;
                    int sum = 0;

                    while ((count = fileStream.Read (buffer, sum, length - sum)) > 0) {
                        sum += count;
                    }
                } finally {
                    fileStream.Close();
                }

                try{
                    imageData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    imageData = imageData.Replace (System.Environment.NewLine, "");

                    byte[] imageBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String (imageData);

                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream (imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                    ms.Write (imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

                    Image image = Image.FromStream (ms, true);
                    image.Save (args [1], System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Console.WriteLine (e.ToString ());
                }
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine ("Incorrect number of arguments");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This builds perfectly fine in MonoDevelop. But when I go to run the file (given the two arguments) it spits out the following exception:

```
System.FormatException: Invalid length.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Convert:InternalFromBase64String (string,bool)
  at System.Convert.FromBase64String (System.String s) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Base642Img.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I have absolutely no idea what this is saying and all of my searches on Google have turned up blank so I now turn to Stack Overflow hoping that someone can help me with this.

Comment: It means that `imageData` does not contain a valid base 64-encoded string.

Comment: But it does o.O. All pre-existing converters can read the data from the file just fine.

Is there maybe something I am doing wrong while reading it that invalidates the string?

Comment: Right before that line executes, can you debug and see what the values of `imageData.Length`, `imageData[0]`, `imageData[1]`, `imageData[imageData.Length - 2]`, and `imageData[imageData.Length - 1]` are?

Comment: Seems like you make the things  complicated, `var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(File.ReadAllText(filename));
            this.image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imageBytes));`

Comment: @Michæl Liu in order: 516838, R, 0, O, w

Comment: @MichaelLiu I doesn't have to be *multiple of 4*, since it may contain newline chars which will be ignored by *Convert.FromBase64String*

Comment: Should I not strip it of new line characters?

Comment: @BenjaminWilliams Just try my 2 lines of code. Tested. It works...

Comment: @EZI just tested them. Same exception.

Comment: @BenjaminWilliams then your input file is incorrect, because this code works. I can post the sample data if you want.

Comment: The input file is completely correct as other decoders have no problem reading it what so ever. I have tried at least 7 written in different languages and they have all converted it perfectly fine.

Comment: @BenjaminWilliams then good luck, without knowing your input file, we can't help you more.

Comment: Try appending a `=` to the end of the file, and if that doesn't work, append another `=`.

Comment: This question would be simple to answer if you'd have provided the actual base64 data you're trying to decode. Without it, all you get is well-meaning people fumbling about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx) requires that the input string be padded at the end with up to two `=` characters so that its total length (ignoring white-space characters) is a multiple of four. Apparently, the program that created your base 64-encoded file omitted the trailing padding.

You need to append the missing padding characters yourself as necessary:

```
// using System.Collections.Generic;
// using System.Linq;

string imageData = File.ReadAllText(args[0]);
HashSet<char> whiteSpace = new HashSet<char> { '\t', '\n', '\r', ' ' };
int length = imageData.Count(c => !whiteSpace.Contains(c));
if (length % 4 != 0)
    imageData += new string('=', 4 - length % 4); // Pad length to multiple of 4.
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
image.Save(args[1], System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

Note: Since `Convert.FromBase64String` ignores white-space characters, it's unnecessary to remove new-line characters. (My thanks to EZI for pointing this out.)